# Unable to use NSURL in Alamofire response.result.value! Swift, xcode 7.3

Tags: swift, ios9, alamofire, xcode7.3

I have a media player app that I'm working on, and I am sending an Alamofire request to obtain an URL in the form of a string... when I receive the response I do properly receive it as a string, but when I try to convert it into a NSURL, I keep getting nil.

The request is:

```
  Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)  { response in
            print("Response: \(response)")
            print("Response String: \(response.result.value!)")
            self.URLToPlay = response.result.value!
    }
```

My URLString is a String, my URLToPlay is also a String. 
The command I use to convert it to NSURL is

```
  let streamingURL = NSURL(string: self.URLToPlay)
```

I get a valid URL-looking string in URLToPlay, in fact if I copy/paste that received string unto a browser, I am able to play the media... but when I use it to convert to NSURL, my app crashes (due to streamingURL being nil).

Now I believe this has something to do with the request being asynchronous, but I'm wondering if anyone has any idea of how to get this working?

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Edited to use a completion handler:

```
  func connectToServer() {
    print("Connecting...")

    finishLoad { theUrl in

        let urlString = theUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())
        let streamingURL = NSURL(string: urlString!)

  // do what i need to do

    }

    isConnectedToServer = true
    print("Connected...")
}
func finishLoad(complete: (urlToBePlayed: String) -> ()) {
    var aVar: String!
    Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)  { response in
            aVar = response.result.value!
            complete(urlToBePlayed: aVar)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an `Async` process and no matter where you use `URLToPlay` **OUTSIDE**  the `.GET` function of `Alamofire`, it is going to return `nil` because it will be `nil` as the process is async and the variable is still not updated at all. You can wrap this up in a completion handler and use like so:

```
func finishLoad(complete: (urlToBePlayed: String) -> ()) {
let aVar: String!
 Alamofire.request(.GET, URLString, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString(encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)  { response in
            print("Response: \(response)")
            print("Response String: \(response.result.value!)")
            aVar = response.result.value!             
            complete(urlToBePlayed: aVar)
    }
}
```

Now call and use it like so:

```
finishLoad { theUrl in
let urlString = theUrl.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQ‌​ueryAllowedCharacter‌​Set())  //Fixes the deprecated error.
var convertToURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!     
 print(convertToURL)

//here you do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!, I had a sneaky suspicion that I needed to use a "completion handler"... I was just thinking I had to use NSNotifications and observers... but this seems like a good Idea... I will test this in a while and get back to you

Comment: I have added to my original post your example, and I still get an error found nil right after I try to convert a string to NSURL...

Comment: `print(theUrl)` after `theUrl in` and see if it shows anything?

Comment: yep I did that, i do get a valid string... the error comes after the following lines of code where I say: let streamingURL = NSURL(string: theUrl) then I try to use it by saying: self.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: streamingURL!) ... and that's when it crashes, because It's trying to use streamingURL but it's nil... so the conversion of "theUrl" to NSURL is what's giving me nil

Comment: I think this will work, I saw it previously in one of my searches, but the problem is that I get a warning saying it's deprecated... but for now, yes it works I get a valid URL to use with AVPlayerItem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Fixed the deprecated warning. Please accept the answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: I get the following error: Type 'NSCharacterSet' has no member 'URLQ‌​ueryAllowedCharacter‌​Set'

Comment: What version of swift are you using?

Comment: The one that comes with Xcode 7.3, but I found out I just needed to add this: NSCharacterSet, accepting your answer! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm hoping I can add one last question which is still part of the issue, when the convertToURL does return a valid URL but, it adds a "%0a" at the end, would you know how to remove this or how to prevent this? Thanks!